# How to update the textInput with the values retrieved from sqldf() in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am currently developing a shiny App and I am unable to update the textInput with the values retrieved by using **sqldf()** from the dataframe.
The dataframe looks like this

```
             Email First Last
1 abc.yyz@gmail.com   abc  yyz
2 vvv.rrr@gmail.com   vvv  rrr
```

The issue is when I select the Email,it should display the first name in the textInput1 and last name in TextInput2.

The code used is:

```
if (interactive()) {

  ui <- fluidPage(
    selectizeInput('email', 'Enter Email ID', choices = sam,options = list(
      placeholder = "Please select your Email ID",
      onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))),
    textInput('fn', ' Enter your First Name'),
    textInput('ln', 'Enter your Last Name')
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

      observeEvent(input$email,{
        check <-  paste(input$email)
        fetchvalue <- sqldf("select * from dataset where `Email` == 'check'")
        first <- fetchvalue$First
        updateTextInput(session, "fn",value = first)
      })


  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Can anyone help to solve this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are first name and last name inputs? If they are populated by selecting email, aren't they basically outputs?

Comment: Initially, Email, First Name, Last Name are the columns in the data frame. The Email Id is given in the selectizeInput(). When an Email Id is selected then the corresponding first and last name are retrieved from the data frame and it is filled in the corresponding textInput(). Is it clear? @Shree

Comment: I know what you are trying to do. I am only asking why the name fields are inputs and not outputs? Do you want the user to be able to enter different names irrespective of what you get from your dataframe?

Comment: Yeah. The corresponding data should be displayed. If I need to edit the data, I can edit it and those changes are to be reflected in the data frame

Comment: can you confirm that `fetchvalue` in `observeEvent` is correctly pulling data? Try putting `print(fetchvalue)` right below it and check your R console while running the app.

Comment: It does not fetch values!! It creates a data frame with 0 records.. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Try `sqldf(sprintf("select * from dataset where Email = '%s'", input$email))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app code looks fine. Here's a mwe for your app -

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectizeInput('email', 'Enter Email ID', choices = paste0(letters, "@example.com"), options = list(
      placeholder = "Please select your Email ID",
      onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))),
    textInput('fn', ' Enter your First Name'),
    textInput('ln', 'Enter your Last Name')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$email,{
      # check <-  paste(input$email)
      fetchvalue <- data_frame(Email = paste0(letters, "@example.com"), First = LETTERS) %>% filter(Email == input$email)
      first <- fetchvalue$First
      updateTextInput(session, "fn", value = first)
    })
  }
)
```

As mentioned in my comment, I suspect your `sqldf` query in is wrong. Try this instead

`fetchvalue <- sqldf(sprintf("select * from dataset where Email = '%s'", input$email))`